# JMeter 5.0: How to send HTTP Request with body data?

Tags: jmeter, postman

This may be a duplicate from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40514004/jmeter-how-to-send-get-request-with-body-data

But despite the guys on that question claiming it is solved on version 3.1 of JMeter, it is not working as I expected on JMeter 5.0.

I also tried to set Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded on a HTTP Request Manager associated to the HTTP Request Sampler but the body is only passed on POST requests. My app receives nicely from Postman but not from JMeter.

EDIT: This is the Code snippet generated by Postman:

`GET /api/patients/5c1e35351f68df799c0ad864/cases HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:3080
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJlbWFpbCI6InJ1YmVubWFycXVlczkxQGdtYWlsLmNvbSIsInVzZXJJZCI6IjVjMjNiZTJkNjU0YjIwMzhiNDQwY2ViZiIsImlhdCI6MTU0NjAxMjQ2NSwiZXhwIjoxNTQ2MDE2MDY1fQ.LqCV9eHByxQ0ubDIcJOwR0WGGXfMw49X0VLLurjbseM
cache-control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 2d8f4f4c-4ec6-428e-bf1a-cafd27fa98ed
{
    "caseName": "TestName"
}------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--`

Answer (score 1):

What exactly doesn't work? For example, given the following Elastic search payload:

```
{
  "index": {
    "_index": "shakespeare",
    "_type": "act",
    "_id": 0
  }
}
{
  "line_id": 1,
  "play_name": "Henry IV",
  "speech_number": "",
  "line_number": "",
  "speaker": "",
  "text_entry": "ACT I"
}
```

When I execute the following GET request:

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "play_name": "Henry IV"
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

I can see the request body exactly as I defined in the [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener

[image]

And the response contains all the relevant search results:

[image]

---

So I would recommend comparing the requests which are being sent by Postman and JMeter using a sniffer tool like [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) or [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/). Most probably there is an error in JMeter configuration, presumably connected with wrong [Content-Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type)

---

Also be aware that it is possible to record the request sent from Postman using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder)

1. Prepare JMeter for recording. The easiest way of doing this is using [JMeter Templates](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-save-%E2%80%98loads%E2%80%99-time-using-jmeters-template-feature) feature

   - from JMeter's main menu choose `File -> Templates -> Recording` and click "Create"
   - Open HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder and click "Start"
2. Prepare Postman for recording

   - from Postman main menu choose `File -> Settings -> Proxy`
   - tick both `HTTP` and `HTTPS` protocols and set proxy server to `127.0.0.1:8888`

     [image]
3. Execute your request in Postman
4. JMeter should capture it under the [Recording Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Recording_Controller). If everything goes well you should be able to replay it without any issues.

Comment: The problem is that the body of the request is empty on the server side. But it is not when using Postman...

Comment: The problem is that you're configuring JMeter differently and expect the same behavior. Same requests will produce the same response.

Comment: I know, I just can't point out what I'm doing differently. I setup the recording as instructed, I think, and it didn't record anything into the Recording Controller by the way.

Comment: Click `code` button in Postman and update the question with the request: https://i.stack.imgur.com/851pU.png

Comment: Ok, I've updated the question

Comment: I managed to configure the recording stuff at least now.

Comment: There's something VERY interesting going on here. If I send the GET request from Postman directly, my server gets the body of that request, but if I proxy it using Postman + JMeter the body is empty!

Comment: I don't see any body, I see [Authorization](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization) header which you need to provide in JMeter using [HTTP Header Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-http-header-manager)

Comment: It's the last line ```caseName=TestNameundefined=undefined``` don't know why the undefined stuff though. The Authorization stuff is working. Now sending raw JSON from postman, question updated

Comment: @DmitriT I had a problem in a test plan I'm using. Also for call to Elasticsearch. When I use the GET method, JMeter won't send the request body (but with POST it does). The json is in the body tab. The content-type is set correctly.  Do you know why this might be happening? I see you used GET with a json body here. I'm using JMeter 5.2.1 . It says here https://www.thetopsites.net/article/52273610.shtml that this shouldn't be possible (for unknown Jmeter version)

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in the configuration o JMeter. I was using the Parameters tab of HTTP request and putting properties on the Name tab and values on the Value tab.

An illuminated user posted this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51609079/3267330.

I don't know why my initial approach worked on POST, PATCH and PUT requests and not on GET requests specifically, but now I'm just sticking with putting the body of all my requests on the Body Data tab and creating a Header with `Content-Type: application/json` because THAT works!

Comment: I had added the required Header as Content-Type: application/json - but still it was not working because by mistake in the encoding field I had added application/json as well - hence data was not being send.

Comment: Content-Type: application/json - do the job on my side